# How to retrieve attachement file From Custom list sharepoint2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, custom-lists

I have create custom list..and submit Form data onto list by Visual webpart.but i have doubts when i have attach on the attachments of list.
now a time to retrieve Data from custom list but how can i retrieve attachement file from list and easy to download by End user???
Plz anyone guard me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SPFolder folder = web.Folders["Lists"].SubFolders[list.Title].SubFolders["Attachments"].SubFolders[listitem.ID.ToString()];
```

Then you can do:

```
foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)
{
    // Do what you want to do with the file
}
```